# Is there a way to prevent step-into during debugging ?(VSC++ debugger)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

For example, i start the process, and some reason I misused some standard library or window library. The debugger will always jump into the headers of the standard library and indicate a breakpoint there. Therefore, I could not track where this error occurs inside my source code. Is there a way to prevent this step-into and only break on certain scope? Or is there a way to track down which line inside my source code is calling this standard/window function?

I just want to prevent trying to insert multiple breakpoints and track down the error.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Breakpoints have nothing to do with step into vs step over. If you are stepping, use F11 to step into, and F10 for step over, and shift+F11 to step out of.

Comment: Hard to guess what this really is asking, sounds like you hit an assert().  Just use Debug + Windows + Call Stack window to trace back to the line of code you wrote that caused the problem.

Comment: Are you debugging a release build? That can be confusing, with inlining and optimisation blurring the relationship with your original code. A debug build is easier.

Answer (score 0):

If debugger breaks in some standard library code, open Call Stack window and find your own code which caused this. In more complicated case, you will not see your own code in the stack - for example when, some memory is corrupted. In any case, debugger breaks exactly where an error is detected, this is useful functionality, and it works only by this way.

Call Stack window is available in the Debug menu.